# Security risk in java server?

Tags: java, linux, security, sockets

I got here 2 simple codes:

Server:

```
package myserver;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class MyServer {

public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception {
    String clientSentence;
    String capitalizedSentence;
    ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(6789);
    while (true) {
        Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
        BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
        DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
        clientSentence = inFromClient.readLine();
        System.out.println("Received: " + clientSentence);
        capitalizedSentence = clientSentence.toUpperCase() + '\n';
        outToClient.writeBytes(capitalizedSentence);
    }
    }
}
```

Client:

```
package myclient;

import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

class MyClient {

public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception {
    String sentence;
    String modifiedSentence;
    BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 6789);
    DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
    BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
    sentence = inFromUser.readLine();
    outToServer.writeBytes(sentence + '\n');
    modifiedSentence = inFromServer.readLine();
    System.out.println("FROM SERVER: " + modifiedSentence);
    clientSocket.close();
}
}
```

Now.... If i open this server to public, is there any security risk by sending modified packages and getting into the system? (Server is using some Linux dist.)
Or is it only possible to send simple Strings?

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code would just read a sequence of bytes and print them out (and send a response). As far as I know, this is has totally no risk.

Answer (score 0):

Somebody could crash the Java process by sending it lots of data with no newlines. Depending on how much memory you gave the JVM, this could impact the server running the program.